# MySQL ROLLBACK and use with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
COMMIT;
```

I have taken this query directly from the MySQL official documentation and I am wondering certain aspects (I added myself the FOR UPDATE). Supposing that there is another user that already has a lock on the record. In that case the update should fail. If that were to happen I am wanting for sure a way to display to my user a message box that will alert the user that there is a lock on the record. How might I get that information back into PHP? Also wouldn't this query roll back by default or do I specifically need to add the ROLLBACK?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is a single query. If there is nothing dependent on it, there is no need to transaction here. And rollback is not needed, since if query fails to update the row, there are no changes to roll back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset the value of **autocommit** variable to **OFF / 0 / FALSE**. 
Try this:

```
SET SESSION autocommit = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Supposing there were a current lock on that record. What would happen?  Is there some way to detect that state perhaps by way of adding a variable?

Comment: Query wait till another query release the lock on the table.You can check the status of any query using **show full processlist**.

Comment: That's very interesting. I searched the internet of how I might check the status of a query but I'm not yet returning anything. It sounds like I need to put a few sample programs together to try this out.